# How could allowing a moon shot in hearts benefit the other players?

Tags: hearts

I was playing online with experienced players. The high guy was about 55; the other three were between 15 and 25. The high guy attempted to shoot the moon; I prevented him. I was roundly criticized by another player for stopping the moon shoot. The criticism was that allowing him to shoot benefitted "the three of us."

For the life of me, I cannot understand why that would be a good idea. What am I missing?

Comment: Likely this question needs more details: obviously allowing a player to shoot only benefits that player. The rules are explicit on that point. So either the other players are wrong or they have alternate goals beyond the base game (perhaps related to the online site).

Comment: Thanks. We weren't playing for money or anything like that, so it was just a game for the sake of a game. The guy was so incensed by me blocking the shoot that he left the game -- couldn't be bothered to further dally with such a brainless amateur. But why he would want us to voluntarily give up our roughly 30-point leads each....I cannot understand. And I guess I can't understand it because he's just dead wrong for some obscure reason.

Comment: Sounds a lot like they're playing for the lucky trophy rather than winning the game. Makes sense if you've won so many games you stop caring and are more interested in being able to claim a rare achievement, but none at all if you're outside that social meta-game.

Comment: What did it cost you to stop him? For example, did you take 1 point? 4 points? 13 points?

Comment: @ryanyuyu if it cost him 1 or 13 or anything in between, none of those supports the assertion that allowing the shooter to shoot the moon would've benefitted the three other (non-shooting-the-moon) players.

Comment: If I recall, the would-be shooter ate most of the points.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. This guy got so bent out of shape -- acted as if I had ducked six straight tricks to allow someone to win -- that I had to second-guess myself. He asked why I did it. I said....uh, instinct? The only scenario I can think of where you would allow someone to shoot would be if by doing so he put someone out yet you would still finish low and therefore win.

Comment: OT: I played tennis with a friend once. They told me off, because I wasn't hitting the ball back to them. That's just not cricket.